# Paypal Chain Payment

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am creating a demo for Paypal chained payment. 
I have created a pre-approval key.
Then created a chained payment using pre-approval key and got a pay key. 
It shows me response status as success but payment status is incomplete. 
Below is response :

```
Array
(
    [Errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [Ack] => Success
    [Build] => 13414382
    [CorrelationID] => f46b0bc553e93
    [Timestamp] => 2014-12-20T02:26:21.492-08:00
    [PayKey] => AP-7V269507JS839270K
    [PaymentExecStatus] => INCOMPLETE
    [RedirectURL] => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-7V269507JS839270K
    [XMLRequest] => ReturnAllen_USPAY_PRIMARYhttp://sandbox.domain.com/cancel.phpAPP-80W284485P519543T27.109.15.19USDPRIMARYRECEIVERPA-9Y121769RW083710840.00business-manager@gmail.comtrue20.00personal101@gmail.comfalsehttp://sandbox.domain.com/return.php
    [XMLResponse] => 2014-12-20T02:26:21.492-08:00Successf46b0bc553e9313414382AP-7V269507JS839270KINCOMPLETE
)
```

Please help me in this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is because the secondary receiver has not been paid.

Answer (score 1):

PAY_PRIMARY results in a "delayed chained payment" which means the secondary receiver will not get their funds until a follow-up call to the ExecutePayment API has been made.  If this is not what you intended, but rather a regular chained payment, use PAY instead of PAY_PRIMARY.